# Clear browser cookie during SAML back channel SLO (SOAP)

Tags: soap, jersey, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

Is it possible to clear browser cookies during a SAML backchannel SLO communication?

In my case, a Service Provider (SP) initiates a logout from the browser via SOAP. The IDP, on receiving the SLO request, clears the record for the session with this SP and the other participating SPs. However, I need to clear the local cookie for my IDP host as the session is currently determined by the presence of this username cookie. The UI decides if the user is logged in or not based on the presence of this cookie. Not sure how can I achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

The endpoint that gets hits for the SLO-

```
@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_XML, "application/soap+xml"})
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public Response postLogoutMessageSOAPBinding(String logoutRequestString)
            throws OpenSAMLException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, UnmarshallingException, LogoutFailureViaSAMLSoapException, SAMLTokenGenerationException, MarshallingException, NoResponseException {
        if (logoutRequestString == null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Received bad logout request via SOAP binding.");
            return Response.status(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        } else {
            Object requestXmlObj = logoutUtility.getObject(logoutRequestString);
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope) requestXmlObj;
            LogoutRequest logoutRequest;
            if (envelope != null) {
                if (envelope.getBody().getUnknownXMLObjects().get(0) instanceof FaultImpl) {
                    FaultImpl fault = (FaultImpl) envelope.getBody().getUnknownXMLObjects().get(0);
                    throw new OpenSAMLException("Received soap fault message for SLO response- " + fault.getCode() + " " + fault.getMessage());
                }
                if (envelope.getBody().getUnknownXMLObjects().get(0) instanceof LogoutRequest) {
                    logoutRequest = (LogoutRequestImpl) envelope.getBody().getUnknownXMLObjects().get(0);
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Received unknown soap message body of "
                            + envelope.getBody().getUnknownXMLObjects().get(0).getSchemaType());
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new OpenSAMLException("SOAP envelope cannot be null...");
            }
            Envelope responseSoapEnvelope = wrapSOAPResponse(processLogoutRequest(logoutRequest));
            String responseXML;
            try {
                Element plaintextElement = envelopeMarshaller.marshall(responseSoapEnvelope);
                responseXML = SerializeSupport.nodeToString(plaintextElement);
                LOGGER.debug("ResponseXML : " + responseXML);
            } catch (MarshallingException e) {
                throw new OpenSAMLException("Response SOAP envelope marshalling exception: ", e);
            }
            return Response.ok(responseXML)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if the cookie references something in a session at the IdP, can the IdP just delete the session data? The cookie is really just a pointer to data at the IdP. If the IdP deletes the data the cookie's presence doesn't matter as there is no session so the IdP should go through the authentication process again.

Comment: @codebrane We are using cookies to maintain the state on the browser side. That's how we started by design. So currently, each screen on the website reads if the cookie is available (This cookie is created during login) and accordingly shows the logout button and the username on the screen.

Backend APIs also reads this cookie as cookie param and accordingly decides if the user is logged in and redirect to the SP.

So essentially If I can somehow clear this cookie during SOAP based SLO, everything would work as expected.

Comment: @codebrane Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: I only use cookies as a pointer to stuff on the server, e.g. in the session. The fact the cookie exists doesn't mean anything until the server has verified what it points to is valid. That's why deleting the session during SOAP logout will invalidate the cookie, whether it exists or not. If the presence of the cookie is the important bit, rather than what it points to, I don't know how you could delete it when not using the browser (SOAP).

Comment: @codebrane Thanks, this gave me a lot of insight. I think that I should follow a similar approach of pointing the cookie to session data on the server.